# Unable to install package using luarocks on osx

Tags: macos, lua, homebrew, luarocks

I installed lua on my OSX 10.10 machine using `brew install lua`. The version that got installed was 5.2.4. LuaRocks was installed along with the lua package. But when i run `luarocks install <package_name>` i get `Error: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@ does not exist and your user does not have write permissions in`. i tried using `sudo luarocks install <package_name>` as well, but it gives the same error. How to fix this ?

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: try `brew update` and `brew doctor` and check for more warnings in the output.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I note that  `@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@` has been written in the file `/usr/local/etc/luarocks52/config-5.2.lua` as the root of the system rocks tree. Presumably it should be `/usr/local` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in the way we relocate text files to ensure wider bottle portability for non-/usr/local users.

It was resolved a couple of weeks back, July 31st I believe. Presuming your Homebrew is in a standard location, if you do:

`rm /usr/local/etc/luarocks52/config-5.2.lua && brew update && brew reinstall lua`

The problem should be resolved now. Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using the luarocks when installed with homebrew, try installing luarocks again like this:

```
$ wget http://luarocks.org/releases/luarocks-2.2.1.tar.gz
$ tar zxpf luarocks-2.2.1.tar.gz
$ cd luarocks-2.2.1
$ ./configure; sudo make bootstrap
```

I took this code snippet from here: https://luarocks.org/
I managed to install all the modules that I required without problems after doing this.